# Physical Device is added but not showing in debugging menu

Tags: ios

Somehow I added my physical device iPhone 6s (ios 13.5.1) but it is not showing in simulators menu. Can anyone help?
Restarted Xcode many times or reattached device as well. 
[image: Image 1: Not showing my physical device in debug dropdown.]
[image: Image 2: Showing my added physical device successfully.]

Comment: When you attach screenshots make sure it's being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `Show as run destination` is checked.

[image: Devices and simulators]

Comment: Where is that option btw?

Comment: Yes it is checked!